# How to upload image to API in React Native via FormData

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, form-data

I am available to upload  image to server via postman: 
Here is a picture of my postman config.
[Postman Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpAK5.jpg)
I am using Axios and here is my config:

```
uploadPhoto = () => {
    let formdata = new FormData();
    let i = {
      uri: this.state.profilePhoto.uri,
      type: "multipart/form-data",
      name: `image.jpg`,
    };
    formdata.append("user[image]", i);

    console.log("This is formdata", formdata);
    Axios.put(EDIT_PROFILE_API, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        apisecret: this.props.api_secret,
      },
      body: formdata,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        response.text().then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "Image is not uploaded");
      });
  };
```

It gives me an error when i try upload it to server. What i am doing wrong?

I am getting this error message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUdzk.png)

Comment: What is an error?

Comment: it says data can not be read. Promise error

Comment: console.log("This is formdata", formdata); are you able to see this value in console?

Comment: yes i can see value, it is array with key user[image] and value is object of width, height, image uri, type

Comment: This issue is fixed, i found what was the issue

Comment: Hey what was the issue? will you write an appropriate answer below to reference for all.

Comment: issue was that my backend was accepting only png files and iwas sending jpg files

Comment: glad you rid out of your problem. :)